# cdb commands in Visual Studio debugger, like WinDbg?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, windbg

Does anyone know whether Visual Studio's debugger has a cdb command console so that I could input commands like in WinDbg? Eclipse has a command console where you can issue commands to gdb, and Xcode has a command console where you can issue commands to lldb, but I can't find anything like this in Visual Studio.

Just to be a bit more specific, I'd like to be able to execute things like `.reload` or `X *!*some_symbol*` like you can in WinDbg/cdb.

Comment: You can debug your program completely in WinDbg after you are done with compilation using visual studio. Based on my understanding Visual studio does not have any plugin short of thing which allows us to use WinDbg as backend debugger.

Comment: @MantoshKumar: yes - and that's what I've been doing. But ideally I'd like the best of both worlds. On OSX I can use Xcode's very nice visual debugger, but then dive down into lldb at any point to get at something more detailed. Visual Studio's debugger hides everything under the hood - it seems like any challenging debugging problem really needs to be handled in WinDbg.

Comment: That used to work fairly well, you could load debugger extensions with the !load command from the Immediate Window.  But not anymore, the debugger interface changes starting in VS2012 cause major trouble.  If you want to use cdb then just run it.  Hard to see the point to it btw, the debugger built into VS is very, very capable.  Use the Debug + Windows + Modules debugger window to troubleshoot symbol loading problems, just right-click an entry and select Symbol Load Information.

Answer (score 1):

There's the command window:

```
View -> Other Windows -> Command Window
```

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

I dont think `x` or `.reload` is available as Visual Studio autoloads all symbols by default.

For a list of predefined aliases type `alias` in the Command Window and take a look.

```
Debug.modules
select module with symbol problem -> right click context menu ->symbol xxx
```

should show what is the problem with symbol load (same as windbg !sym noisy output)
you can also force load all symbols with 
`Debug.OptionsAndSettings -> debug -> symbols -> load all symbols` set the cache to _NT_SYMBOL_PATH srv folder so that it downloads the neccesary pdbs if required

Comment: Unfortunately the whole reason I want to use a cdb interface in visual studio is because sometimes VS *doesn't* load all symbols by default. It can be useful to look at the module list and find out why, or to force a symbol reload. Tracking down symbol loading problems with Visual Studio is a real pain point. Xcode and Eclipse CDE both let you delve down into the guts of the underlying debugger to fix these things, but not Visual Studio, it seems.